# Scrapy inside Azure functions throwing "signal only works in main thread"

Tags: python, scrapy, azure-functions, web-crawler

I have implemented webcrawling upto certain depth. my code Skelton is below.
class

```
class SiteDownloadSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Regex pattern to match a URL
    HTTP_URL_PATTERN = r'^http[s]*://.+'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SiteDownloadSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        print(args)
        print(getattr(self, 'depth'), type(getattr(self, 'depth')))
    
        self.MAX_DEPTH = int(getattr(self, 'depth', 3))
        self.BASE_URL = getattr(self, 'url', '')
        print(self.BASE_URL)
        self.BASE_URL_DETAILS = urlparse(self.BASE_URL[0])
        self.BASE_DIRECTORY = "text/" + self.BASE_URL_DETAILS.netloc + "/"
    
        # print("in the constructor: ", self.BASE_URL, self.MAX_DEPTH)
        self.visited_links = set()

    def start_requests(self):
    
        if self.BASE_URL:
    
            # Create a directory to store the text files
            self.checkAndCreateDirectory("text/")
            self.checkAndCreateDirectory(self.BASE_DIRECTORY)
            self.checkAndCreateDirectory(self.BASE_DIRECTORY + "html")
            self.checkAndCreateDirectory(self.BASE_DIRECTORY + "txt")
    
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.BASE_URL, callback=self.parse, meta={'depth': 1})
        else:
            print('no base url found')
    
    def parse(self, response):
        \#somelogic

def crawl_websites_from_old(start_urls,max_depth):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(SiteDownloadSpider, input='inputargument', url=start_urls, depth=max_depth)
    process.start()

    # logger.info(f"time taken to complete {start_urls} is {time.time()-start} in seconds")
```

**Azure function code**

`

```
@app.function_name(name="Crawling") @app.queue_trigger(arg_name="azqueue", queue_name=AzureConstants.queue_name_crawl,connection="AzureWebJobsStorage") @app.queue_output(arg_name="trainmessage",queue_name=AzureConstants.queue_name_train,connection="AzureWebJobsStorage") 
def crawling(azqueue: func.QueueMessage,trainmessage: func.Out[str]):
     url,depth=azqueue.get_body().decode('utf-8').split("|") 
     depth = int(depth.replace("depth=", ""))
     crawl_websites_from_old(start_urls=url,max_depth=depth)
```

**ERROR**

`Exception: ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter Stack:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 493, in _handle__invocation_request     call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 762, in _run_sync_func     return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper     result = function(**args)   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\function_app.py", line 58, in crawling     crawl_websites_from_old(url,depth)   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\web_scraping\crawl_old.py", line 337, in crawl_websites_from_old     process.start()   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 420, in start     install_shutdown_handlers(self._signal_shutdown)   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\ossignal.py", line 28, in install_shutdown_handlers     reactor._handleSignals()   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 142, in _handleSignals     _SignalReactorMixin._handleSignals(self)   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\projects\ai-kb-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1281, in _handleSignals     signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, reactorBaseSelf.sigInt)   File "C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal     handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))`

How to make sure my crawling logic works fine. I dont have enough time to re-write the crawling logic without scrapy